# when hovering over an image, how can I make two or more images change?

Tags: css, image, hover

Im taking an interactive class at pasadena art center and we were assigned to make a website that involves image hover overs. usually, what students will do is to create a hover over on one image, but I want to make it so that when you hover over an image, multiple images on the page will change.

I read some forums on ways to do this, but the only solution I can find is through java script. The only problem is we can only use dreamweaver and CSS.

Do any of you guys know how this can be achieved by only using CSS and/or basic html?

Comment: When you say you can only use dreamweaver, javascript works in dreamweaver. You can use the "Live Code" button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when hovering over an image, how can I make two or more images change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328580/when-hovering-over-an-image-how-can-i-make-two-or-more-images-change)

Answer (score 0):

If your tutor has told you that you're only allowed to use HTML/CSS, then I don't think you'll be able to do it - CSS:hover psuedoclass will only effect the element being hovered.

If you're allowed to use Javascript, then your desired effect is definitely possible.

I've put together a quick example of how one could do this: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/vhG2b/5/).

Comment: can you tell me how I can achieve this by using javascript?