# when hovering over an image, how can I make two or more images change?

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I was wondering if you can tell me how I can do the following: when hovering over an image, two or more images change.

Im kind of new at this, so please give me clear directions

Answer (score 2):

Adapt this example to suit.

```
var image1 = document.getElementById('image1'),
    image2 = document.getElementById('image2'),
    image3 = document.getElementById('image3');

image1.onmouseover = function() {
   image2.src = 'whatever.jpg';
   image3.src = 'something.png';
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by that? you mean just copy + paste that whole code in dreamweaver CSS?

Comment: @Ken You can't really do this in CSS - well only if you can use background images and the other two images are descendent images. The code above is JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have ichat by any chance? since Im new to this its really hard to explain my intentions...

Comment: Is there any way I can chat with you?

Comment: @Ken I'm sorry, I don't provide (unpaid) answers outside of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ken W, `image1` would be your image id such as `<img id='image1' src='myimage.jpg' />`

Comment: Im sorry, I still dont understand what you are saying. I am using CSS+HTML on dreamweaver... can I still do what I want to do by using that?